# Sequelize eager loading with create method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When a new post is created I want user details with it. I searched in sequelize docs couldn't find anything helpful. Right now I'm using additional method provided by sequelize on model but it is executing 2 queries.

```
let createPost = await db.Post.create({
      content: content,
      postedBy: req.session.user.id,
    });

let user = await createPost.getUser({ attributes: ['id', 'firstName'] });
```

How can I get postedBy user details back with post details in one query?

Comment: All in all DB should execute INSERT for `post` and SELECT for `user` to get new post and to get a user record linked to it

Answer (score 0):

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const db = require("../models");

describe('db', () => {
    it('insert', async () => {
        let createPost = await db.user.create({
            name: 'test'
        });
        var user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createPost))
        console.log(user)


    })
})
```

Output

```
{
  id: 5,
  name: 'test',
  updatedAt: '2021-03-05T15:08:59.245Z',
  createdAt: '2021-03-05T15:08:59.245Z'
}
```